# asp.net core Iactionresult two post error

Tags: asp.net-core

in my asp.net core project, the form is being posted 2 times, but I have examined it, there is no form on the html side, or I removed the entity code, it still posts 2 times, what is the reason?

```
public IActionResult save()
        {
            return View();
        }

[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult save(example entity)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _unitOfWork.repository.savechagn(entity);
                TempData["Message"] = _MessageBox.Success;
                return Redirect("list");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.ModelStateErrors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).ToList();
                TempData["Message"] = _MessageBox.Error;
                return View();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Do you mean the save httppost action be called twice? Could you provide the minimal executable code? Just based on this code is difficult to find the reason.